# How to detect if android application is minimized or not in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I would like to detect if my application is minimized (I mean press home button) or not, using Kotlin. Note that I am not talking about any specific activity or fragment, I mean whole of the application. I need to assume three separate state for application: Showing in the view port, minimized, and completely closed. How should I detect first two states? If android lifecycle can do this, please describe how. Thank you!

Comment: Use `ProcessLifecycleOwner`.

Comment: I read it, but what I cannot understand is ON_RESUME and ON_PAUSE can do what I need or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If app home button is pressed you can check with a `LifecycleObserver` in `Application`

```
inner class ApplicationObserver : LifecycleObserver {

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
    fun onPause() {
    }
    
}
```

To detect when uses swipe and kill your app you can use a Service and you can register it with

```
   ProcessLifecycleOwner
            .get()
            .lifecycle
            .addObserver(ApplicationObserver())
```

or override Activity's onUserLeaveHint method which runs when home button is pressed.

```
/**
 * Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is about to go
 * into the background as the result of user choice.  For example, when the
 * user presses the Home key, {@link #onUserLeaveHint} will be called, but
 * when an incoming phone call causes the in-call Activity to be automatically
 * brought to the foreground, {@link #onUserLeaveHint} will not be called on
 * the activity being interrupted.  In cases when it is invoked, this method
 * is called right before the activity's {@link #onPause} callback.
 *
 * <p>This callback and {@link #onUserInteraction} are intended to help
 * activities manage status bar notifications intelligently; specifically,
 * for helping activities determine the proper time to cancel a notification.
 *
 * @see #onUserInteraction()
 * @see android.content.Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION
 */
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
}
```

To detect when user swipes right and finishes your app you can use a `Service` and override

```
override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)

    setRestartAppAlarm()
}
```

We used this method for a showcase app which required app to be working all the time. When a customer in a shop closes the app we set an alarm and restart it again.

Comment: Thank you! All in all, ON_RESUME and ON_PAUSE is what I need. am I right?

Comment: I advise you to check out Activity lifecycles, and test how they work because it's one of most essential parts of Android. onStart is called first time app is visible, onResume first time user can interact with the app and onPause is called when there is a transparent Activity above your app or you push home button and it's called before onStop. But onPause does not indicate whether user closed you app or not. Test these methods with toast message or log and see which one fits your needs best.